# Php codes are not executing in required order

Tags: php

This is what's happening when I'm executing this php file. And I'm using XAMPP server.

[image]

Comment: Its not possible. May be your are executing other file

Comment: And what have you tried to find the "error"?

Comment: Also post your code here instead of upload images

Comment: That code isn't generating that output. The rendered HTML shows "Javascript" in a different face.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are editing the wrong file. Stop wasting people's time by denying it.

Answer (score 2):

I see `test_2` on your Notepad file title.

And `test_2.php` on your browser.

Maybe the Notepad hides the extension.

Make sure you don't have two different files.

Comment: file is same.Just while running on browser, it shows extension.

Comment: PHP is a synchronous programming language, your output doesn't seem possible. Make sure you are really opening `myPhp_projects/test_2.php`.

Comment: @rahulraj, I doubt that. Edit your question and show us a screenshot of the `myPhp_projects` directory in Windows Explorer.